# What determines the number of inodes available on a disk?

Tags: inode

Is it based on a number determined when formatting a hard drive?

For instance:

```
$ df -Ti /
Filesystem     Type Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0      ext4 983040 95683 887357   10% /
```

Where does that 983040 come from? Can we increase/decrease it? Within what limits?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'll assume that you were just testing if I was paying attention ;-)  (I often look at the edit history, before posting comments, and of course this time I hadn't).

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking about ext4 filesystems, it's based on the size of the filesystem.  Defaults to 1 inode per 16,384 bytes.  More information at [Archwiki - ext4 - bytes per inode ratio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4#Bytes-per-inode_ratio)

Note that this ratio **can** be revised at the time of filesystem creation, see [man page for mkfs.ext4](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4)

To address the subsequent edits to the question, where you added some questions:

> Where does that 983040 come from?

It comes from the filesystem size.  1 inode per 16,384 bytes of filesystem, by default.

> Can we increase/decrease it?

Yes, but not easily.  Backup the filesystem, recreate the filesystem using the "-i bytes-per-inode" argument in the man page.  Restore the filesystem contents.

> Within what limits?

As shown in the man page, bytes-per-inode should not be set to less than the block size, otherwise you're *likely* to have more inodes than could ever possibly be used.  As  Stéphane Chazelas points out, empty files, devices, fifos, sockets, short symlinks consume an inode, but don't consume a block.

Do you **really** need to create more than 887,357 further files in the root filesystem ?

Comment: empty files, devices, fifos, sockets, short symlinks take one inode, but no block, so it's technically possible to use up the whole inode table while using very little data. So in some (OK contrived) situations, it may make sense to have bytes-per-inode smaller than the block size.

Comment: Note that the `-i bytes-per-inode` is calculated based on the size of the  block device, that is not the ratio size_in_the_fs/number_of_inodes, but block_device_size/number_of_inodes. For instance, with a `mkfs -b 4096 -i 4096` on a device that is 10MiB large, you'll get 2560 inodes, but only about 5MiB of space available, so it will be more around 2KiB  per inode.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a per-disk measure, it's a per-filesystem measure. For many filesystems, yes it is determined at format time. For some filesystems, it's dynamic based on the filesystem usage, average file size, and other bits of information.